# opencv trackbar not showing

Tags: visual-c++, opencv3.0

## include

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat srimg, deimg;

int max_brightness = 100;
int slider_b = (max_brightness / 2);

void on_change_brightness(int, void*)
{
    int brightness = slider_b - (max_brightness / 2);
    deimg = srimg + Scalar::all(brightness);
    imshow("Girl", deimg);
}

int main()
{
    srimg = imread("lenna.PNG");

    imshow("girl", srimg);

    createTrackbar("Track", "Window", &slider_b, max_brightness,on_change_brightness);

    waitKey();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note:: when I run the code it works well no error, but the track bar does not show up, and to my knowledge everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OpenCV [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=createtrackbar),

> int createTrackbar(const string& trackbarname, const string& winname,
>   int* value, int count, TrackbarCallback onChange=0, void* userdata=0)

Thus, your window name should be "Girl"

I think the line

`createTrackbar("Track", "Window", &slider_b, max_brightness,on_change_brightness);`

should instead be

`createTrackbar("Track", "Girl", &slider_b, max_brightness,on_change_brightness);`

and the line

`imshow("girl", srimg);`

should instead be

`imshow("Girl", srimg);`

to keep a common window name.

If this doesn't work out, try

`namedWindow("Girl", 1);`

above the createTrackbar function.
Source: [Example](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/highgui/trackbar/trackbar.html)